# How can create, list, and destroy be performed in one view at a time in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a like model to implement the like function and made a corresponding view so that it would be good to send a post request. By the way, I am going to implement this one view to be unlike if I receive a delete request at once. So I will first use get method to get one like model and then map the pk of that like model to url. But when I send a delete request to the view, the following error appears.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\feed\views.py", line 138, in destroy
    super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 90, in destroy
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 88, in get_object
    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (

Exception Type: AssertionError at /feed/post/12/like
Exception Value: Expected view CreateReadLikeView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
Request information:
```

How can I implement a delete request from one view? Here's my code.

views.py

```
class CreateReadLikeView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    is_saved = False

    def get_queryset (self) :
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        postId = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=postId)

        try :
            like = self.queryset.get(post=post, liked_people=self.request.user)

        except Like.DoesNotExist :
            serializer.save(liked_people=self.request.user, post=post)
            self.is_saved = True

    def create (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        if self.is_saved is True :
            self.is_saved = False
            return Response({'success': '해당 게시물을 좋아요 했습니다.'}, status=200)

        return Response({'message': ['이미 해당 게시물을 좋아요 하였습니다.']}, status=400)

    def list (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        postId = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=postId)

        try :
            like = self.queryset.get(post=post, liked_people=self.request.user)

        except Like.DoesNotExist :
            return Response({'message': ['좋아요 하지 않음.']}, status=400)

        return Response({'success': '좋아요함.'}, status=200)

    def destroy (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        postId = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=postId)
        
        try :
            like = self.queryset.get(post=post, liked_people=self.request.user)

        except Like.DoesNotExist :
            return Response({'message': ['좋아요 하지 않음.']}, status=400)
        #It will include a code that sends a delete request using like.pk.

class DeleteLikeView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsLiker]
    queryset = Like.objects.all()

    def get_queryset (self) :
        return super().get_queryset().filter(post=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))

    def destroy (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'success': '해당 게시물의 좋아요를 취소했습니다.'}, status=200)

        #When a request is received from the CreateReadLikeView, you try to activate this view.
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post', CreateReadPostView.as_view({'post': 'create'})),
    path('post/all', CreateReadPostView.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    path('post/<int:pk>', UpdateDeletePostView.as_view({'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'})),
    path('post/<int:post_id>/comment', CreateReadCommentView.as_view({'post': 'create'})),
    path('post/<int:post_id>/comments', CreateReadCommentView.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    path('post/<int:post_id>/comment/<int:pk>', UpdateDeleteCommentView.as_view({'put': 'update', 'patch': 'partial_update', 'delete': 'destroy'})),
    path('post/<int:post_id>/like', CreateReadLikeView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list', 'delete': 'destroy'})), # If this url receives a delete request,
    path('post/<int:post_id>/like/<int:pk>', DeleteLikeView.as_view({'delete': 'destroy'})), # The view delete try sending a request to write code.
    path('post/<int:post_id>/like-people', ReadLikerView.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
]
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py` file and the URL you send DELETE request to

Comment: @GProst I add it